# Frequency generator using Arduino

Tags: arduino, frequency

Arduino has an function of generating frequency via `tone()`. But it is limited to int value which is 1 Hz in steps. Is there any ways that I can generate frequency with 0.1Hz of resolution?

I have also tried using simple arduino programming by simply set the pin to HIGH, certain delay, and set the pin to LOW and then the certain delay. Then the program loops itself. Is this way we can also able to generate the frequency?

Comment: Using the qt tag is unnecessary

Comment: oh dear, I'm sorry. thanks for noticing

Comment: `Delays` or `interrupts` can be used to generate the certain frequency.

Answer (score 0):

As the functions name indicates tone() is for creating tones. No one can hear 0.1Hz so there isn't much need for that.

If you want to create low frequency oscillations you can use many other things.
You can implement it yourself using timers, or delay functions as you already tried or you use code other people have written.
It all boils down to controlling outputs over time.

Searching the web for Arduino frequency generator should overwhelm you with tutorials, libraries and circuit or code examples. To be honest I don't see any point in your question given the amount available of resources online.

Comment: `Searching the web for Arduino frequency generator should overwhelm you with tutorials, libraries and circuit or code examples.` 

I've already done that, don't your worry.. abundance of tutorials but don't have what I wanted. I've tried the delay function but it is unstable and inaccurate in generating frequency. Some of the tutorials shared online can give the resolution of 0,1Hz, but at high frequency.is there any way to generate a low frequency of 0.1hz from range of 0.1 Hz to 1000.1Hz??